# Word get current line as integer

Tags: c#, ms-word

how can I get the current line in a word document as an integer? Is this even possible?

```
  public void Export(string filename, string name, string value, DataGridView dg, int iRows)
    {
        oWord = null;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        object lineNo = missing;

        // Get word instance.
        ExportData.GetWordInstance(ref oWord);

        if (oWord != null)
        {
            try
            {
                int iPos = 1;

                oDocs = oWord.Documents;
                // Open document.
                object fileName = DirectoryFiles.OpenFile(filename);   
                object readOnly = false;
                object isVisible = true;
                object oMissing = Type.Missing;
                oDoc = oDocs.Open(ref fileName, ref oMissing, false, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

                oBookmarks = oDoc.Bookmarks;

                if (name == "bookmarkPositions")
                {
                    int rows = dg.Rows.Count * 3;
                    object oEndOfDoc = "bookmarkPositions");
                    Word.Table oTable;
                    Word.Range wrdRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
                    oTable = oDoc.Tables.Add(wrdRng, rows + 1, 5, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                    // ....
```

That's how I try to solve my export ...

Thanks for help!

Comment: What constitutes the "current line"? - More details needed.

Comment: The line of the cursor

Comment: For example if I am at line 50 a page break would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

the first problem I solved by myself. 
To have the header of the table on each page I insert the following:

```
     oTable.Cell(1, 1).Row.HeadingFormat = -1;
```

Now the main problem:

```
   for (int r = 0; r < dg.Rows.Count; r++)
       {
          oTable.Cell(j, 5).Range.Text = datagridview1["price", r].Value.ToString();
           ....
       }
```

In each row I have a sum. 
At the end of each page respectively at the end of the table at a page I want to insert a new row with the current sum.

How can I do this??